# How can you get the percentage of completion from the server for jquery progress bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page that submits a form to a servlet, and the servlet does some processing and then sends an excel file back to the browser for download.  Sometimes this processing can take a long time.  How can I use a progress bar to show the user the percentage of progress made by the server?

I know a progress bar can be made like this:

CSS:

```
.ui-progressbar { 
height:20px;
width:300px;
margin:0 auto;
}   

.ui-progressbar span { 
width:300px;
position:absolute;
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

And in the jsp page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
         $( ".progressBarClass" ).progressbar({
              value: 50
         });
    });
```

```
<div class="progressBarClass"><span>50%</span></div>
```

But I am not sure how to get the value to be the percentage of progress made by the server.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone Can you explain with a little more detail?

Comment: In your servlet that's doing the work, you can periodically save the progress to a database, with a sequential or randomly generated job number that the client side code know about and the servlet uses to update the database.  Then in your client-side code you can periodically send another Ajax request to a different servlet that simply reads the progress from the db.

Comment: @davidbrainerd I like this idea.  My question regarding this idea would be this - let's say the servlet that is doing the work sometimes takes 5 seconds, sometimes 5 minutes, or sometimes an hour. When you say "save the progress", how do you determine how much of the overall task is completed in order to save that progress?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does your servlet do to create the Excel file?  Do you know the number of rows in advance?

Comment: @developerwjk I believe I could compute the number of rows that will eventually go in to the excel file. But the part of the code that takes a long time are some computations that happen on a resultset retrieved from the database. The result of these computations is a "list" that ends up being written to the excel file. So, is there any way to track the progress of the "computations"?

Comment: @developerwjk If there isn't a way to keep track of the computing explained above, and I do just use the number of rows that will go in to the excel file, that would be better than nothing. How can I display the progress if I am using the number of rows?